# Stop Excel 2010 from automatically unhiding columns when entering a formula into a cell

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with data in columns `A` through `Z`.  I have hidden columns `B` through `Z` such that my sheet's columns look like `A AA AB AC ...`.  When I start entering a formula into cell `AA1` and subsequently press the left directional key to incorporate a value from column `A`, Excel will instead unhide all the columns between `A` and `Z` forcing me to scroll through all of these to get to `A` (even though, with the hidden columns, `A` was right next to `AA`).  Is there any way to force Excel to keep columns hidden during cell formula entry?  I have looked into the options, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that checking `Transition navigation keys` under `Lotus compatibility` in the `Options` menu leads to this behavior.  Unchecking it solved my problem.